# Django: How can I inject a jinja2 variable into a template tag to then return the output

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to pass a jinja2 variable to a function as a parameter but I am unsure of the syntax or method to do so.

I've tried including the reference in the jinja2 function call but this has not worked.

I've tested the function and it works with a simple string "test" and the value is render in the page.

**HTML SECTION**

```html
...
<tbody>
{% for test in test_records %}
    <tr>
        <td class="trGrey"> {{ test.id }} </td>
        <td class="trGrey"> {{ test.testname }} </td>
        <td class="trGrey"> {{ test.created }} </td>
        <td class="trGrey"> {{ test.recordtype }} </td>
        <td class="trGrey"> {{ {{ test.recordtype }}|my_function }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
...
```

**PYTHON FILE**

```py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def my_function(value):
    if value:
        return value
    return ''

register.filter('my_function', my_function)
```

I'd expect the input variable to be rendered to the page.

Any suggestions will be helpful thanks!

Comment: You mention Jinja2 in your question, but since you have `from django import template` it looks as if you are using the Django template language, not Jinja2.

Comment: @Alasdair I think you're right there, I was informed on a online tutorial it was jinja. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a template tag, but a template *filter* (note the `register.filter(..)`), you just filter with a vertical bar:

```
{{ test.recordtype|my_function }}
```

This is described in the [Jinja documentation on *filters*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#filters):

> Variables can be modified by filters. Filters are **separated from the variable by a pipe symbol (`|`)** and may have optional arguments in parentheses. Multiple filters can be chained. The output of one filter is applied to the next.